# How to generate a compilation error when pointer types differ?

Tags: c

How do I write a macro CHECK(a, b) that generates compilation error when the two pointers a & b have different base type.

```
CHECK((int*)0, (char*)0) -> compilation error
CHECK((int*)0, (int*)0) -> works
```

I'm looking for some C89 code, but C99 + gcc extensions will also do.

Comment: What do you mean by "base type"?

Comment: for int* the base type is int

Comment: Can you compile in C++ mode? Then it would be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** now works for any type, not just pointers

Something more or less lifted from the linux kernel, using the GCC extension [`typeof()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).

This generates a warning at compile time, it also works for integer pointer types

```
#define CHECK(a, b) do { \
    typeof(a) _a; \
    typeof(b) _b; \
    (void) (&_a == &_b); \
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *foo;
    int *bar;
    char *baz;

    CHECK(foo, bar);
    CHECK(bar, baz);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It won't work for pointers to integer types - compiler will promote smaller type to bigger one and no error will occur

Comment: have you tried it?
for this program gcc outputs the following: `a.c:16: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast`

I always compile with the `-Werror` flag, btw.

Comment: Anyway, pointer types do not get promoted, that would make very little sense. their dereferenced contents might, but they aren't being examined here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using macros. If you can use C++, then take a look [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=detecting+convertibility+and+inheritance+at+compile+time&source=bl&ots=YQfD-vSg6U&sig=ODSMB8BB9iZ9nkbpFilNAWY-iMQ&hl=en&ei=gmeKSubGHc_IkAWYzpgx&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
#define CHECK(A,B) do { typeof(*A) _A; typeof(*B) _B; _A = _B; } while (0)
```

If your base types and not integer types (char, int, short, long, long long), types will not be promoted so assignment `_A = _B` will fail.

I don't think there is a way to make it working for integer types.